# Series specific annotation attributes

Tags: charts, google-visualization

Does anyone know a method, for google charts(in this case a Combo Chart), to have different annotation styles for different series?

Something like this:?  So far I have only been able to apply annotation attributes in the options section, applying to all series equally.  Thanks!

```
        series: {
        3: {
                                annotations: {
              style: 'default'

              }
        },
        4: {
                annotations: {
              style: 'line'

              }
         }
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can set different colors, stem lengths, etc.

but it appears the style can only be set globally,
as it does not change with the series...

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawStacked,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawStacked() {
  var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Month', 'A', {role: 'annotation'}, 'B', {role: 'annotation'}],
    ['Aug', 3754, '3,754', 2089, '2,089'],
    ['Sept', 900, '900', 200, '200'],
    ['Oct', 2000, '2,000', 4900, '4,900'],
    ['Nov', 1700, '1,700', 2200, '2,200'],
    ['Dec', 2400, '2,400', 2089, '2,089']
  ]);

  var options = {
    annotations: {
      //style: 'line',
      textStyle: {
        fontSize: 10
      }
    },
    series: {
      0: {
        annotations: {
          stem: {
            color: 'cyan',
            length: 5
          },
          style: 'point',
          textStyle: {
            color: 'cyan'
          }
        }
      },
      1: {
        annotations: {
          stem: {
            color: 'magenta',
            length: 10
          },
          style: 'line',
          textStyle: {
            color: 'magenta'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```